# How to build opencv_ffmpeg.so for Linux/MacOS

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg

How to build opencv_ffmpeg.so like opencv_ffmpeg.dll in Windows for OpenCV use in java app.
I followed build guide of FFmpeg.org but when build completed, it just generated many lib*.so.
How to build opencv_ffmpeg.so for shipping in my java application and load it dynamically when app runs?

Comment: Where did you get `FFmpeg.dll` from on Windows? Why are you building FFmpeg in order to use OpenCV? Why do you think you need a single .so?

Comment: I am sorry, it is opencv_ffmpeg.dll not ffmpeg.dll.
I want to use ffmpeg with opencv in Linux like in windows in java application. I want a single .so file for shipping with my java app and load it   at runtime.

Comment: So where did you get opencv_ffmpeg.dll from? A single library containing the entirety of those projects is going to be pretty big. You should only include the ones you actually need.

Comment: opencv_ffmpeg.dll in 3rdparty folder in https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/2.4.13.zip.
How can I know exactly which lib I need to ship with my apps? I don't know the OpenCV APIs I used base on wich libs? Example: What lib VideoCapture in OpenCV  base on ?

Comment: Instructions are here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/ffmpeg